# SQL Server: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (version = 11.00.5388) and I'm getting an exception

> SQLState :23000, Error Message:
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__MM_DISK___C9EB385C43CE19EE'.
>
> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MM_DISKDATA' The duplicate key value is (1484539200000, 40020675, 1, 40611)..]

while trying to insert a record into the table `MM_DISKDATA` even the entries are unique am getting the exception.

Example entries:

```
insert into MM_DISKDATA 
values('1484539200000','40020675','1','40611','79','79','948','12','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1');

insert into MM_DISKDATA 
values('1484539200000','40020676','1','40611','79','79','948','12','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1');
```

`MM_DISKDATA` has first four columns as unique constraint.

Please help with this.

Comment: "Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MM_DISKDATA" - that is a very clear and precise error. So don't insert duplicates!!

Comment: @MitchWheat entries are unique. even its showing the above exception

Comment: No they clearly are not!  Does the table have a trigger on it?

Comment: Please **show us** the table structure! What are the columns - which name and datatype? What kind of constraints do you have on the table? What column(s) make up the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query in the database to find out which columns are the PK columns for the table MM_DiskData:

```
SELECT C.Name 
FROM sys.index_Columns IC
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I
    ON IC.index_id = I.index_id
    AND IC.object_id = I.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.Columns C
    ON C.object_id = I.object_id
    AND C.column_id = IC.column_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(IC.object_id) = 'MM_DISKDATA'
AND I.is_primary_key = 1
```

Once you have that list, you'll be able to see which columns are supposedly causing your problem.

To clarify for yourself, you might want to list out the columns receiving the data in your `INSERT` statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO MM_DiskData ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4],...[Colx])
VALUES ('1484539200000','40020675','1','40611',...'-1')
```

If you compare the list of values you're trying to `INSERT` to the list of values returned by the query posted up above, you should get an indication of why the error is being thrown.

Good luck.